# How to make UAC ask for username and password every time?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-10, uac

if i start a CMD with elevated rights the UAC asks for the password of my current user, which is only a normal user. So i need to switch the user under "weitere Optionen" (more choices)

[image]

If i start a setup i get directly prompted for username and password appears.

[image]

Can i configure windows (GPO) to always (eg. start cmd.exe) ask for username and password in UAC dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

For this edit the local security policy start **secpol.msc**.  When started go to **Local Policies > Security Options and look for "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval mode"**
The standard setting for administrators is **"prompt for consent"** but you would want to change it to **"Prompt for credentials."**

Comment: The default on my fresh Win10 1803 is "Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries" an changing to "Prompt for credentials" or "Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop" doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: After changing, did you run gpupdate command?

Comment: Yes and i restarted the system.